# Conflicting descriptions of JavaScript closures

Tags: javascript, closures

After a lot of reading and hacking, I feel that I am finally starting to understand JavaScript closures and their uses.  However, some of the resources I've read have worded things in a way that seems possibly slightly contradictory to me.  Or, maybe I'm just reading into them too much.

An excellent article from helephant.com ([link](http://helephant.com/2008/10/17/javascript-closures/)) states that:

> Closures are created when a function that’s nested inside another function accesses a variable from its parent’s scope.

And...

> The closure is actually created when the outer function exits, not when the inner function is created.

I understand both of those points in the context of the examples given.

However, a more basic tutorial from John Resig's site ([link](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#49)) states that the block of code below has a closure in it.

```
var num = 10;

function addNum(myNum){
  return num + myNum;
}

addNum(5);
```

Pretty much any **useful** example of a closure I've seen would return a reference to the inner function and do something with it later.  So this example seems kind of pointless, but whatever, let's try to accept and understand that it is still a closure regardless.  However, when I try to integrate helephant's concept (the closure is not created until the outside function exits) and hack it up a little, I come up with this:

```
function outerFunction() {
    var num = 10;

    function addNum(myNum){
      return num + myNum;
    }

    alert(addNum(0));

    num = 5;
}

outerFunction();
```

Now, according to Resig, `addNum` creates a closure.  According to helephant, the closure is not created until `outerFunction` returns.  However... the closure (if it really is a closure) uses a value of `num` from **before** when `outerFunction` exits.  Contradiction?

Admittedly, since I **called** `addNum` before `outerFunction` exited... it does seem logical that it would use the current value of `num`.  But this makes me question Resig's statement that the simple example he presented is indeed a closure.  But... who am I to question Resig?  Surely I am misunderstanding something?

To make this fit the Q&A format better, here are my questions boiled down:

(1) Is Resig's example (and my extension further down) a closure?

(2) If yes, why does it use a value of the enclosed var from before the outer scope returns?

Comment: You can think of the global execution context as the outer function in Resig's example. It returns when the code is done executing and thus a closure is created.

Comment: Though a very interesting topic to discuss I think this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion and therefore is probably not a good fit for the expected Q&A format.

Comment: @AlexW Right, I get that.  But my confusion with helephant's words still hold in that case.  In Resig's example, we can change the value of `num` before the global scope ends, and the closure will use the **first** value of `num`... not the one that existed at the end.  Also, to be more pedantic, what is the point of an object that is created at the moment the global scope ends?  That's why I used an explicit `outerFunction` in my extension, to try to make it seem more like a real code case.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Ok, here are the Q's more explicitly.  (1) Is Resig's example a closure? (2) If yes, why does it use a value of the enclosed var from before the outer scope returns?  OP has been edited to include these!

Comment: @DaveJohnson: All very debatable to be honest and you will find a lot of answer will say one or the other or even completely different. I personally took my understanding from Crockford's JavaScript the good parts and think I understand it in my own way, though it still confuses me occasionally. This is [**a video version of the good parts**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook#!) and closures are at around 30mins 12seconds. We also got wikipedia which sums it up nicely too in a sentence. The rest is good for a discussion but not Q&A in my humble opinion.

Comment: It seems that the "enclosed value set to what it was when outer function exits" rule only holds true if the inner function has not yet been called.  If inner function is called before outer function exits, it uses whatever the value is at that moment.

Comment: @DaveJohnson Exactly. The inner function gets a copy of the outer function's variables and their values when it is called.

Comment: @AlexW Ahh... I think that concept made it click.  If a reference is returned, then it can't be called until **later** which is why it will then be stuck with whatever the final value of those inner scoped vars was.

Comment: @alexW technically the inner function gets a reference, not a copy.  In sure that's what you meant, but the distinction is important.

Comment: @ben336 Any primitive type in Javascript like strings and numbers are passed into a function by value, not reference so I did actually mean a copy.

Answer (score 2):

So this isn't a contradiction as much as quibbling over semantics.  It seems like you've got a pretty good understanding of the situation, your descriptions of how closures work appear to be accurate.

From [its Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) (originally from Sussman and Steele. "Scheme: An interpreter for extended lambda calculus". )

> In computer science, a closure (also lexical closure or function closure) is a function or reference to a function together with a referencing environment—a table storing a reference to each of the non-local variables (also called free variables) of that function. A closure—unlike a plain function pointer—allows a function to access those non-local variables even when invoked outside of its immediate lexical scope.

So a closure is technically just a function that has a referencing environment (a reference to an outer function scope in javascript).  But what makes it special is that it can then be called from another scope.

So technically Resig's example is a closure.  It is a function with a reference to an outer environment.  Its outer environment happens to be the global scope, but it still has one.  But its not distinguishable/special compared to other functions till its passed.

In the end its not wrong to call any of these examples closures.  But for them to be  useful compared to a generic function, you're going to want to pass it out of the calling context.

Answer (score 1):

`window` actually has a function-scope in and of itself.

`window` exists both with a function-scope (`var bob = "Bob";`) and with object properties (`window.bob = "Bob";`).
In typical usage, they're the same, but in actuality, they aren't.

```
window.bob = "Bob"
delete window.bob;
window.bob; // undefined

var bob = "Bob"
delete window.bob;
bob; // "Bob"
```

So closures happen any time a scope you're running in has access to an outer function's scope.

***BUT*** the reason I would not say that `window` provides a closure is simply that `window` is globally-accessible.
That is, every piece of code on the site has access to `window`'s function-scope.
Therefore, it's not really "enclosed", as you haven't prevented access to it.

What you can take from this is that the example which relies on the global-scope is the same technique which closures are built on, and thus is the easiest and most-general way to start grasping them...

...but, because those values aren't hidden to the outside world, after the fact (through the outer function returning), there's no real closure happening.

Comment: If we focus on my last code block, we can forget about `window` altogether which makes things a bit more straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

So the point that is being demonstrated with closures is that the inner function can hang on to the outer function's variables even outside of the outer function's scope.

The inner function inherits a copy of the outer function's variable and value via Javascript's [prototypical inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) and the second variable assignment has not been evaluated yet in the outer function's scope, so the inner function will inherit a copy of the currently assigned value.

Good showcase of this behaviour:

http://jsfiddle.net/JD32X/

```
function outer()
{
    var test = "hello";
    var blah = function() { window.alert(test); };
    blah();
    test = "not hello";
    blah();
}
outer();
```

Comment: "The inner function inherits a copy of the outer function's variable and value" No, the inner function shares access to the same variable as in the outer function. It is not "a copy".

Comment: @newacct Javascript is always pass by value but some values are references to objects. Therefore changing a string will have no effect on the outside variable, but changing an object property will. It's known as the "call by sharing" evaluation strategy.

Comment: JavaScript is pass by value, but this is not passing we are talking about. This is the capturing of variables by a closure. "Therefore changing a string will have no effect on the outside variable" Why don't you try it and see?

Answer (score 0):

@DaveJohnson, Hello. 
Let me try explain why `The closure is actually created when the outer function exits, not when the inner function is created` is a true statement.

When you define a new variable within some scope (function), this variable is created and `lives` within this scope. When the function returns, the normal thing to happen is that no reference to that variable is held, so it should not exist anymore. It will be "garbage collected". However, if some inner function (scope) uses this variable and keeps a refference to it **after the outer scope has returned** - a closure is created. Thus it is said that `The closure is actually created when the outer function exits, not when the inner function is created.`
In your example:

```
function outerFunction() {
    var num = 10;
    function addNum(myNum){
        return num + myNum;
    }
    alert(addNum(0));
    num = 5;
}
outerFunction();
```

the num variable is created when calling outerFunction and is fully released when the function returns. Why? Because no reference to that object is held after that. Actually the inner function addNum is also created in that scope and it will not exists after outerFunction returns. So I **do not see a real closure** here.

**Edit:** *what we see here is nothing more than just `SCOPING`. Yes - inside the addNum function a reference is MADE to variable from the outer scope, but that variable has not been `enclosed`. It will be `enclosed` if just in that place in the code you assign the addNum function as event handler to a button click event for example. That way the function itself as an object will continue its existance after outerFunction has returned, because a reference to that function will exists in the button click event and in that case a reference to the `num` variable will also exist.*

If you create the addNum function that way:

```
...
window.addNum = function(myNum) {
     return num + myNum;
}
...
```

that's would be completely different case. A closure is created here, but it can be said, that **this happens when the outer function returns**. Why? Because that is the moment when the `num` variable should be "garbage collected", which won't happen, because there is still a reference to the object.

There is a pretty good explanation of what a closure is. Imagine your outer scope as a marriage. This scope is actually a house in which you live with your family - you have a wife, two kids, furnitures, etc. They all are properties and functions created inside the marriage 'scope'. When you get devorsed, you get kicked out of your house (The function 'marriage' has returned), but you still keep references to the objects created within your marriage and these objects would be your two children :). As for your wife - she won't exist anymore in your own 'scope' as wife and your furnitures will no longer be yours :)

**UPDATE**
What I meant to explain to you in the first place is that `'The closure is actually created when the outer function exits, not when the inner function is created`' in your example applies to addNum function, but NOT to the outerFunction, because no closure is created after outerFunction exits.

**UPDATE 2** - it's not about enclosing a value, but a reference

```
// man is not the value "Jonh Resig"
// it's a pointer to SOME 'man', existing in the memory
var man = "John Resig";

function haveSex(woman) {
     return man + woman; // creating a baby;
}
haveSex("Some Girl");      // baby of "Some Girl" and Resig
man = "Douglas Crockford"; // changing `man` reference to point to another object
haveSex("Some Girl");      // baby of "Some Girl" and Crockford
```

Comment: Thanks.  I see things as you do, yet it still confounds me that a JS guru like Resig says [-this-](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#49) is a closure.

Comment: Well... yes.. :). In that example of Resig a closure is created. There are two global objects created - the `num` variable and the `addNum` function. The function itself has `enclosed` the num variable in its body. And even if you write `delete num;` and then execute the addNum function, you will see that this object still exits and has kept its last value. In your example - nothing survives after the outerFunction exits and about helephant statement - yes, closure is created whit addNum exit, but once outerFunction returns, nothing stays there. At the end it's all about scope we look at:)

Comment: Actually, it's not possible to delete `num` in Resig's example.  Try it yourself.  But instead of deleting it, you can change its value and then re-call `addNum`.  And `addNum` does **not** use a previously enclosed value... it uses the value that you just set yourself in the outer scope.  I see no proof of enclosure in this case.

Comment: Hi, it's not about enclosing a `value`, but an `object` - a place in the memory. And in that situation you actually have two pointers to that place in the memory. I am mistaken about the delete, but my point was, that if you somehow manage to delete one of the pointers to that object, it still won't be garbage collected, because another reference will keep it alive. I believe understanding the difference between a value and a reference (pointer) will help you understand that. Creating a closure is creating a `implied` reference to an object.

Answer (score 0):

Ben McCormick is correct, I just want to expand on his answer and explain how what he wrote applies to the helephant article (but I don't have enough reputation points to add a comment).

When helephant wrote that comment, he was making a specific point.  Using my own example to make the same point, consider the following code sample - we loop to create 10 functions, put them in an array, then loop through the array and call them:

```
function getFunctions() {
    var functions = [];
    for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        functions.push(function() { window.alert(i); });
    }
    return functions;
}
functionArray = getFunctions();
for (var j=0; j < functionArray.length; j++) {
    var f = functionArray[j];
    f();
}
```

Helephant is warning you not to be confused:  This alerts the number "10" ten times.  It does not alert 1, 2, 3, ... 10.  But his terminology and explanation is not completely precise.
When `function() { window.alert(i); }` is executed, the system does create a closure.  As Ben McCormick states, the closure consists of 2 pointers.  One points to the function definition (the parameters of the function and the function body).  The other points to the environment.
In our example, all 10 closures point to the *same* environment.

Again - to be really technically precise, there are 10 closures, but only one environment.
This environment is where `i` is bound to "10".
This should make intuitive sense.  `var i` is only executed once, so there is only one instance of `i`.  `function() { window.alert(i); }` is executed 10 times, so there are 10 closures.  But all 10 closures point to the same environment.